# Is it possible to run x86_64 programs on ARM32?

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, x86, emulators

I've recently bought a micro:bit and I would like to use it with my Raspberry Pi 4 using Mu (a python IDE).
I coded the program which should display "Hello World" on the micro:bit, however I got an error message stating that I needed the latest version of Mu to do this. The version I have is 1.0.3, which is the latest version available for my Pi (The latest Mu version is 1.2.0) . I went onto the Mu website to download the AppImage file for the x86 linux build for Mu, however it is compiled for x86_64. I have an x86 emulator, however I do not have a 64 bit emulator. So is there any way for me to run the latest version of Mu on my Pi?
Thank you for your time.